# Is the transparent thin layer on top of my broth gelatin?

Tags: stock, broth, bones

I let a bone broth simmer over night and I woke up to a transparent, thin, and almost plastic-looking like layer that creases easily when moved on top of the broth. Is this gelatin? I'm just checking that it's not something I should discard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably fat, which congeals (and sometime solidifies, depending on how much) at the surface of cold broths and stocks.  Gelatin will often be distributed throughout, and if there in sufficient quantities, your chilled stock will be jello-like.

Comment: ime gelatin usually ends up distributed throughout the broth, there may be more of it at the bottom, but the entire broth usually ends up jellified when chilled. I agree 100% that this will be fat

Comment: @Tristan yes good point...guess I was thinking more of a confit situation.  I will edit.

Comment: thanks! in hindsight it seems more obvious that it was fat, i'm not sure why i so confused.